# At most two of the events $A$, $B$, or $C$ occur? Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: Consider a sample space $S$ and three events $A$, $B$, and $C$. For each of the following events draw a Venn diagram representation as well as a set expression.  At most two of the events $A$, $B$, or $C$ occur?

I'm having a challenge understanding the solution to this, which is:

$(A \cap B \cap C)^c = A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c$

and the following diagram:
[image: Venn]

I can see from the Venn Diagram that only two events may occur due to the intersection visually, however not so with the set expression.  Is the diagram necessary to understand this solution or is there some property of the set expression that can be used to explain the solution "At most two of the events $A$, $B$, or $C$ occur"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in A\cup B$ means $x$ belongs to at least one of the sets between $A$ and $B$, might belong to both.

So $x\in A\cup B\cup C$ means $x$ belongs to at least one of the sets among $A,B,C$.

$x\in A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c$ means $x$ belongs to at least one of the sets $A^c,B^c,C^c$, that is to say, 
 for at least one set $A,B,C$, $x$ does not belong to it. So $x$ can belong to at most two of them.

Edit: Here's an example as asked by OP in the comments, consider the universe of tossing $3$ coins, i.e the entire sample space is $\{HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT\}$ and consider the events: 
$A=$ exactly one head 
$B=$ at least one tail 
$C=$ last toss is a head

so that we have the corresponding sets: 
$A=\{HTT,THT,TTH\}$ 
$B=\{HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT\}$ 
$A=\{HHH,HTH,THH,TTH\}$

so the event "at most two of $A,B,C$ occur" is the set of those combinations in the sample space where all three don't occur (check below)

$(A\cap B \cap C)^c= \{TTH\}^c=\{HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,HHH,TTT\}$

Comment: It does.  The answer is written in this form: $(A \cap B \cap C)^c = A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c$.  Does that imply the form is satisfied by $!= {emptyset}$?

Comment: Saying "At most $2$ of the events occurs" for a total of $3$ possible events is same as saying "All $3$ events do not occur" i.e. the complement of the occurrence of all three events. The occurrence of all three events $A,B,C$ is what $A\cap B\cap C$ means, we don't want that to happen, so it's complement. The empty set $\phi$ does satisfy the condition "at most $2$ ($\le 2$) events occur", because in case of the empty set $0\le 2$ events occur, if that's what you're asking, but of course it's not the exact set describing "at most $2$ events occur".

Comment: Do you have an actual example using a sample space of elementary events?

Comment: @Nick I have edited an example into the answer. Since this is a fundamental property of set, you can think of any experiment  (like tossing $3$ coins), and define any $3$ events $A,B,C$ (not necessarily distinct) to verify this. Basically, any example you can think of will work.

Answer (score 0):

At most two from $A,B,C$ is: $(A\cap B\cap C)^{\small\complement}$, that is everything except that which is in the triple intersection. (Everything inside the Venn diagram except that in the innermost overlap).

That is to say: everywhere that *at least one does not occur*.

$$(A^{\small\complement}\cup B^{\small\complement}\cup C^{\small\complement})$$